# Выполнение скрипта при его подключении Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

как выполнить метод в скрипте при перебрасывании его на GameObject, те есть метод в скрипте SetTag() при добавлении этого скрипта на GameObject он должен выполнятся.

Comment: Уточните: метод должен выполниться в редакторе при добавлении на объект или в рантайме?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker в редакторе

Comment: Вы меня неверно поняли, я имел в виду редакторный код должен выполниться или код из самого скрипта, вопрос уже разрешился - я неверное прочитал вопрос. Как будет время - отвечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите вызывать метод в классе при накидывании его на объект, можете определить в нём метод [MonoBehaviour.OnValidate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html). Стоит помнить, что данный метод будет работать только в редакторе. Так же он будет вызываться, если вы изменяете через инспектор какое-то из значений скрипта.

Выглядит всё просто:

```
void OnValidate()
{
    ///делать что-то. например, кешировать компоненты
}
```